# Pairing derived class two by two in proper way

Tags: c#, inheritance

Assuming these classes:

```
public abstract class Creature
{ public abstract int MaxLevel { get; } }

public abstract class NormalCreature : Creature
{
    public abstract Type Mutation { get; }
    public override int MaxLevel { get { return 50; } }
}
public abstract class MutantCreature : Creature
{
    public abstract Type Base { get; }
    public override int MaxLevel { get { return 70; } }
}

public sealed class Human : NormalCreature
{
    public override Type Mutation { get { return typeof(Superhuman); } }
    ...
}
public sealed class Superhuman : MutantCreature 
{
    public override Type Base { get { return typeof(Human); } }
    ...
}

public sealed class Dwarf : NormalCreature
{
    public override Type Mutation { get { return typeof(DwarfOnADonkey); } }
    public void SwimLikeADolphin() { ... }
    ...
}
public sealed class DwarfOnADonkey : MutantCreature 
{
    public override Type Base { get { return typeof(Dwarf); } }
    // can no longer SwinLikeADolphin(), this is why DwarfOnADonkey does not heritate Dwarf
    public void JumpOverTwentyFeet() { ... }
    ...
}

...
```

How could I achieved this, getting a connection from each `NormalCreature` to `MutantCreature`, and vice-versa, without *duplicating code*? (if `Human` mutates into `Superhuman`, then I could know that `Superhuman` is the mutation of `Human`, without specifying it)

I also thought about another class, pairing them with tuple, or array[2], but I do not really like this solution.
I also thought about Attributes, but I don't really know if it could do the job nor how to use them properly.

Comment: what do you mean by connection?

Comment: "Composition over inheritance".

Comment: You might be interested in reading my series "Wizards and Warriors", about how trying to do what you're doing often ends in tears for all concerned. The TLDR is: **don't try to embed the rules of your game in the C# type system**.  There is no guarantee that the type system represents the kinds of restrictions or freedoms that you need in your rule system. https://ericlippert.com/2015/04/27/wizards-and-warriors-part-one/

Comment: @FrancescoB. I want to know (for example) what is the mutation of a Human, and what DwarfOnADonkey is the mutation of.

Comment: @EricLippert The issue you show there is the exact same issue that I have, but your solution sounds like 'overkill' for the small game I want to code. Thank you anyway, this was really attractive and accurate!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I finally chose this solution, but I don't know about its acceptability:

```
public enum Race
{
    Human = 0x01,
    Dwarf = 0x02,
    ...

    Mutant = 0x80,

    Superhuman = Mutant | Human,
    DwarfOnADonkey = Mutant | Dwarf,
    ...
}

public abstract Creature
{
    public abstract Race Race { get; }
    ...
}

public abstract NormalCreature : Creature { ... }
public abstract MutantCreature : Creature { ... }

public sealed Human : NormalCreature
{
    public override Race Race { get Race.Human; }
    ...
}
public sealed Superhuman : MutantCreature
{
    public override Race Race { get Race.Superhuman; }
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With inheritance always think 'is a'. A superhuman is a human so `Superhuman` should derive from `Human`.
But a human is of a race, not a human is a race. This means `Human` cannot derive from `Race`. You could use the term 'creature' as a base class for human and dwarf.

I wouldn't use the class hierarchy to save the history of an object.

Comment: I understand what you said about 'Race' and 'Creature'. I've made the change in my code! Also, I will explain a bit more why this hierarchy in my original post.